# Using HashSet for Integers

Tags: java

I have two lists. I want to find the smallest common number in the two. I thought of using HashSet as it doesn't allow duplicates. I can find out the common numbers while adding both list elements to it. And HashSet takes only `constant time` for insertion. This can give me `O(n)` to find the smallest common of two. But how can HashSet insert `n` elements in `constant time`? In this case to add the last element it takes `O(n)` time because to find the right bucket it has to compare hashcode with n buckets in the worst case. Please correct this and Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm seems pretty straightforward:

1. Construct a `HashSet` containing the elements of list `A`.
2. Initialize `min` to be something large like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.
3. For each element in `B`, test if it's in the `HashSet`.  If it is, and it's less than `min`, then update `min`.

In any event, hashing algorithms more or less always make the assumption that the hash is, in fact, a good hash function, and you don't worry about the O(n) worst case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I should have asked the question more staright. I have written the algorithm in my question itself. But what I wanted to ask was How HashSet can insert elements in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the bucket is constant time - it only depends on the hash value of the given object, and not on the existing objects.

Comment: Thanks alot. I have searched in this direction. I assume direct address translation for the bucket id(hashcode) is the root solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in any algorithm book (ex. Corman, Knuth). 
Shortly: bucketIndex = toPositiveInteger(hashcode()) % buckets.length